# Do interference pattern shows up if both slits are replaced with colored glass?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Slit 1 is replaced with red tinted glass while slit 2 is replaced with blue tinted glass. No detector is used! would the interference pattern shows up in this case?

How about I leave slit 1 opens while replacing slit 2 with vertical polarizing film and I fires only vertical polarized light across, would the interference pattern shows up?

Last but not least suppose I install 2 always-on detectors at both slits but I refused to read the data from the detectors, would that affects the interference pattern?

Comment: Have a look at this experiment with electrons. http://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html . Photons would have the corresponding reactions, i.e. the changes would turn plane waves into incoherent spherical waves

Comment: also here  http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys1120/phys1120_fa01/Concept%20Tests/CT3700a.htm . The answer is yes, there are still interference fringes

Comment: @anna v: thanks a lot I'm still trying to figure out your first comment.